# How to use tor-browser on OpenAFS?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

In order to KISS I'd like to keep my `tor-browser` directory on an OpenAFS (1.6.18) mount. OpenAFS doesn't support creation of sockets. How to configure `tor-browser` to use another directory for the socket (I assume `tor` is the only binary which needs one)? If that's impossible what else could I do?

On OpenAFS I can't start `tor-browser` because tor fails to start. It doesn't produce a log which is likely a bug which I might investigate and report separately.

After moving the `tor-browser` directory from OpenAFS mount to `btrfs` it works as expected, but I don't find the socket with `find . -type s` which I don't understand.

I'm using `tor-browser` 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: ye gods! 5.0.1 is *old* and worse [*exploitable*](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox-esr/#firefoxesr38.2.1) Are you sure it's not 6.0.1 you're running? 5.0.1 is almost a year out of date now. as for the issue, do you have any logs to show exactly what is failing?

Comment: Right, I upgraded. Logs aren't available as mentioned in the question.

Comment: In the future if you find yourself in a similar situation, you should be able to get *some* kind of log output by running, for example: `./tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser --verbose` in a terminal. Obviously replacing `en-US` with whichever locale you download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `find . -type s` doesn't return a result indicates that this isn't an issue of sockets being unsupported by OpenAFS or involved at all. As it turned out OpenAFS changed permissions without my notice. After changing them back to the user who starts `tor-browser`, it worked.